# Threading implementation (C#)

Tags: c#

Can you please give me a simple example of program that uses threading? 
I don't understand threading and its use and when to use it. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx).

and a very simple one [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) for a beginner level.